# Error: double-loading config "E:\Node\.npmrc" as "user", previously loaded as "project"

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try to do any npm commands I get this error:

```
Error: double-loading config "E:\Node\.npmrc" as "user", previously loaded as "project"
```

But when I run npm globally with the -g param, it works. E:\Node is my global installation folder that all projects share.
The output of `npm -g config` list is:

```
E:\Node>npm -g config list
; "builtin" config from E:\Node\node_modules\npm\npmrc

; prefix = "C:\\Users\\raherne\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm" ; overridden by global

; "global" config from C:\Users\raherne\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc

cache = "E:\\Node\\npm-cache"
HOME = "E:\\Node"
prefix = "E:\\Node"
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
userconfig = "E:\\Node\\.npmrc"

; "cli" config from command line options

global = true

; node bin location = E:\Node\node.exe
; node version = v18.12.1
; npm local prefix = E:\Node
; npm version = 8.19.2
; cwd = E:\Node
; HOME = C:\Users\raherne
; Run `npm config ls -l` to show all defaults.
```

But I can't run things like npm-audit globally so still need to solve this issue

Comment: @savante i think I uninstalled and reinstalled node. Or did a restart. Can't remember I'm afraid!

Comment: Thanks Rory, I solved too but I don't know what I did was right :))

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue with a work around, I just open the file `firebase.json` and remove the pre conditions for build.

This is my file

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

since I just remove those, you need to ensure `npm run build` is execute before the deploy, by just adding a new script in your `package.json` you still can achieve the same result.

```
{
    ...
    "deploy": "npm run build && firebase deploy --only functions",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in an Azure DevOps pipeline running on a Linux VM. I was installing firebase-tools with a curl call in Bash:

```
- bash: |
  curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

The pipeline would fail with the originally posted error when running the pre-deploy lint for Firebase Functions deploy:

```
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint:fix
```

The fix was to install firebase-tools with NPM, like so:

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Install Firebase Tools
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      npm install -g firebase-tools
```

This leads me to believe this error is a misnomer for issues with the scripts in the package.json.