# Flutter Web Firebase Failed to initialise! Error on the UI not terminal

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-chrome, npm

I built a Flutter app for mobile and now need it to run on the web.

Whenever I run it I get this exact same error:

> flutter run -d chrome

[image: Failed to initialise Firebase error image]

Firebase storage, functions, and Firestore were already set up for iOS and Android. I have firebase cloud functions, so they don't need to be stored in the project directory, but regardless I chose to include Firestore, Functions, and Storage for the firebase init.

Steps taken:

1. Added necessary lines to [project_dir]/web/index.html:

> ```
> <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
> <script> var firebaseConfig = {
>   apiKey: "[nope]",
>   authDomain: "[nope]",
>   databaseURL: "[nope]",
>   projectId: "[nope]",
>   storageBucket: "[nope]",
>   messagingSenderId: "[nope]",
>   appId: "[nope]",
>   measurementId: "[nope]", };    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);</script>
> ```

as per https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web/

And went through the Firebase CLI steps as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios

at the step "Do you want to install dependencies with npm now?" this was my output:

> Error:
> double-loading config "/Users/myname/.cache/firebase/runtime/npmrc"
> as "global", previously loaded as "user"
> at Config.#loadObject (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:571:13)
> at /snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:617:31
> at async Config.#loadFile (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:616:5)
> at async Config.load (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:287:5)
> at async Npm.#load (/snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:195:5)
> at async /snapshot/firepit/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:40:5
>
> NPM install failed, continuing with Firebase initialization...

and went through these posts to try to fix it:
https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/4193
[Error: double-loading config "E:\Node\.npmrc" as "user", previously loaded as "project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74444796/error-double-loading-config-e-node-npmrc-as-user-previously-loaded-as-p)

^ with that post I did the necessary deletion and addition.

https://lists.openembedded.org/g/bitbake-devel/message/13156

I (with little knowledge of npm) ran:

> npm config set globalconfig "~/.global-modules/npmrc"

> npm config set prefix "~/.global-modules" export

> PATH=~/.global-modules/bin:$PATH
>
> npm set global TRUE
>
> rm -rf /Users/myname/.cache/

Firebase init still never successfully npm installed. I ran firebase deploy anyway, just to see, and it actually built and launched on Chrome, and gave the error image seen above.

So I thought maybe trying flutter fire configure steps again would help. I ran

> flutterfire configure

to no avail.

Finally I tried just selecting Firestore for my firebase init and avoid the npm install error altogether. Because functions weren't selected, it didn't try to run npm install. However I got the exact same error in my browser. It is frustrating because there is absolutely no indication about what went wrong. What can I try next?

Comment: (At a stretch, you can add financial incentives in the comments here, but we want to keep questions for the long term, so we prefer them to be focussed on the question at hand.)